# Get an object from external application

Tags: python, vba, class, object

I am new in Python and I want to replicate a class module that I generated in VBA, in VBA I defined the object of an external application as follows:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Application.Dev")
```

To this object I assigned the properties and procedures to work with the external app.

In python I am creating the class as follows:

```
class app_obj():
    def __init__(self, path_config):
        self.path_config= path_config
        self.path_ps= path_config[:-2] + "ps"
```

How do I get the same object from python that I got in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is called a **COM Object**.

First you need to import the COM handler in python:

```
import win32com.client
```

Next you can declare an object, pulling it in with the COM handler:

```
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Application.Dev")
```

Now you can use that object in Python using similar calls that you would in VBA:

```
obj.Method()
obj.property = "New Value"
print obj.property
```

SOURCE: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html